# Understanding the concepts of database dml methods

Tags: dml

I need to have better understanding on database dml metods.Can anyone give link where i can get many examples to study and understand about it.

Comment: first 4 search results on google I get for "dml methods" are precisely what you ask for. (But google may have tweeked search results for my statistics ..) DML = make changes to database. (vs: SOQL= read from database)

Answer (score 1):

Use Data Manipulation Language (DML) operations to insert, update, merge, delete, and restore data in a database. The documentation is [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml.htm)

Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: I am new to salesforce ,Im studying about Database DML methods ie Database.dmloperations but i couldnt find more examples for that topic..

Comment: There is a huge amount of information available at http://developer.force.com/ and you can get your own free developer org and learn with that. Good luck!